# How does a chain of promises return without being consumed/fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, reduce

I'm rather confused about how the code below works.
I expect that after Promise.resolve()  returns a resolved promise - not a pending one -  .then() whould immediately consume it/fulfill it, meaning;
in each reduce callback call, two questions will be asked (the chain of promises) - BUT de-facto they all chain and only on return from the function chainPromises, do they consume each other and run together.

Is this because we're waiting for the 'call stack' to empty and each .then() is waiting for the previous .then() callback to end so it returns a promise, etc.?
How does reduce come into play?

Can someone help me understand the code and the concepts behind it better?

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var readline = require("readline");

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
let questionsData = []; 

promisifyQuestion('How many languages do you know? \n')
  .then((numOfLanguauges) => {
    return chainPromises(numOfLanguauges)
  })
  .then((data) => {
    fs.writeFile("./langs.json", JSON.stringify(questionsData), () => {});    
    return promisifyQuestion('Display lang?');    
  })
  .then(x => {    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(questionsData.find(el => el.name == x)));    
    rl.close();
  });

  
function promisifyQuestion(msg) {    
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(msg, resolve);    
  });
}

function chainPromises(length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < length; questionsData[i++] = {});

  let singleValue = questionsData.reduce(outerReduce, Promise.resolve()); 
//Promise chain does fire only on chainPromises end
  return singleValue;
}

function outerReduce(prevRes, currentElement, currentIndex) {
  return prevRes
    .then(() => promisifyQuestion('language name:'))
        .then(x => {    
      questionsData[currentIndex].name = x; 
              
      return promisifyQuestion('years of speaking it:');        
    })
    .then(x => {
      return questionsData[currentIndex].years = x
    });
}
```

Comment: Some terminology: `resolved` means "it is following another promise" like `Promise.resolve(someOtherPromise)` - you're thinking about _fulfilled_ which is different.

Comment: Isn't that promise returned from Promise.resolved() a fulfilled resolved promise with the value 'undefined'? Then I don't understand how it does not immediately trigger the .then() chain.

Comment: It is, I was just correcting the terminology. That reduce is just a trick for chaining (looping) promises - the reduce builds a chain.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I figured it works similar to forEach when it comes to async code. But I can't seem to figure out how it exactly works with promises.

Comment: Can you include the sample output and how it is different from your expectations?

Comment: @JoshLee the output is fine, it's the way it runs that I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises wait until the JavaScript call stack is empty. The snippet below prints `1 2 3`, indicating that the `.then` callback does not run immediately. Technically speaking they are scheduled in the *microtask queue*, separate from the *event loop*.

```js
console.log('1');
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log('3'));
console.log('2');
```

Your example is longer and more complicated, but it boils down to this.

Some reading material:

- [Tasks, microtasks, queues and schedules](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) (and a [live version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0))
- [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Timing) on MDN

Comment: Sweet! This sits well with what I concluded from debugging the above code. Going to try and understand it better via the linked articles.

Answer (score 1):

> `Promise.resolve()` returns a fulfilled promise - not a pending one - `.then()` whould immediately consume it

Yes, that's correct.

> in each reduce callback call, two questions will be asked (the chain of promises)

No. Only the *first* `then` callback in the chain is *immediately* called. The other `then` calls are not on the initial `Promise.resolve()` value, but rather on the previously returned ones. And those are *not* immediately fulfilled, they resolve with and wait for the promises that the `then` callbacks return.

Comment: If we combine this with Josh Lee's reply then, basically the first .then() callback is sent to the event-loop and waits for the callstack to be empty while reduce continues to chain .then()s. When we return from the function chainPromises the stack is empty, the placed callback is called and the chaine continues. Is this the correct flow?

Comment: @Defaceo Yeah, I've left the microtask asynchrony of promise callbacks aside here. The important part is that `promisifyQuestion` is asynchronous and returns a promise, so when the first `then` callback had run (which happens almost immediately), it waits for the readline thing to (asynchronously!) get an answer and only when that promise resolves, the next callback in the `then` chain will run.